# Mailer not reaching Microsoft email users

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

Clients with Microsoft email accounts such as Live or Office 365 are not receiving the Alert email sent out with the code below. Texting feature and Yahoo and Gmail work. A link is run on the computer prompting a location to be shared and an email & text to be sent out.

The email used to send the email out is through Office 365. Can anyone take a look at this. Am I missing something?

I have tried using PHP Mailer, but it does the exact same thing. Any Help!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

</head>

<body>
<?php 
setcookie("tracker", 1, time()+1800);

$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

//$stripped = substr($queryString,strpos($queryString,"i")+1)

$count=-6; 
$id=substr($queryString,$count,6); 

//start email alert
//connect to database
//db connection
 $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'smart', 'smart', 'smarter'); 

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
    exit;
}

 // associate carrier with correct ending

 $query = "SELECT * FROM `smarter` where id = '$id'";
 $result = $db->query($query);
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

 $email = $row['email'];

 $emailSMS = $row['emailSMS'];
 $ownername = $row['ownername'];
 $txt_alert = $row['txt_alert'];
 $number = $row['phoneone'] . $row['phonetwo'] . $row['phonethree'] . $row['carrier']; // var works
 $emailSMS = 1;
 if ($txt_alert == "yes")
    {
        $email_to = $email . " , " . $number;
    }
else if ($txt_alert == "no")
    {
        $email_to = $email;
    }

//check to see if tag has been registered
if ($_COOKIE["tracker"] == 1) {
$number = $row['phoneone'] . $row['phonetwo'] . $row['phonethree'] . $row['carrier']; // var works

//check to see if tag has been registered


$host = "smtp.office365.com";
$port = "587";
$username = "support@xxxx.com";
$password = "xxxxxx";

$datetime = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
$subject = "Alert";

$mailheader.= "From: " . "Smart Recovery Tag Team <support@xxxx.com>\n";
$mailheader.= "X-Sender: " . "support@xxxx.com\n";
$mailheader.= "Return-Path: " . "support@xxxx.com\n";
$mailheader .= "Bcc: support@xxxx.com";

$body .= "Dear " . $ownername . ", \n\n";

$body .= "Your tag has just been scanned.\n\n";
$body .= "Click here to Login to your profile\n";
$body .= "http://www.tag.com\n";
$body .= "***************\n";
$body .= " Login to your profile to see a map of the last GPS location. \n\n";
$body .= "Scanned on " . $datetime . ". \n\n";
$body .= "Regards,";
$body .= " \n\n";
$body .= "Tag Team";
$body .= " \n\n";
$body .= "Keeping found";
 if ($txt_alert == "yes")
    {
mail($email, $subject, $body, $mailheader, ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
mail($number, $subject, $body, $mailheader, ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
    }
else if ($txt_alert == "no")
    {
mail($email, $subject, $body, $mailheader ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
    }


//send email

$_COOKIE["tracker"] = 0;
}

header("Location: http://www.smartrecoverytag.com/profile.php?id=$id");  
mysql_close($db);
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, MS can be BS at times.

Comment: Did you bother trying to look at your mail server's logs to see what happens after PHP hands over the email? PHP does **NOT** do any delivery of email. it just does the equivalent of walking your envelope down to the street corner and tossing it into the mailbox.

Comment: I looked at the outgoing logs and they are going out- no bounce back or anything, but the client does not receive the email.

Comment: Ask the client(s) to look in Spam box. That should be a message placed after mail's been sent out, on screen. *"Thank you. Please check your Inbox/Spam."*

Comment: I'm assuming that the x's in `support@xxxx.com` are a placeholder for the purpose of this question. It's possible the Microsoft is filtering your email due to spam/phishing reasons..

Comment: If you're going to go to the effort of tagging your question with `phpmailer`, how about you try using PHPMailer? It will ago a long way to dealing with many email issues.

Comment: Why are you connecting directly to Office 365's SMTP server? Are you using them as an SMTP server for your service? Doesn't your ISP provide an SMTP service?